# Copy selected data from a jtable in frame1 to another table in frame2

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable2 in frame1 and JTable1 in frame2. I want to copy and send selected data from table2 to table1. how do i do it ?

```
private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
String sql = "select * from table1 where Bill_No like '"+jTextField2.getText()+"'";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            JFrame NewJFrame2 = new NewJFrame2();
            NewJFrame2.setVisible(true);           
            int i=0; 
            while(rs.next()) {
            Object bno = rs.getString("Bill No");
            Object bamount = rs.getString("Bill Amount");
            Object btds = rs.getString("TDS");
            Object btax = rs.getString("Tax");
            Object bpayable = rs.getString("Payable");      

            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bno,i, 0 );
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bamount, i, 1);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(btds, i, 2);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(btax, i, 3);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(bpayable, i, 4);              
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I am expecting some issue due to which you have posted here...but you haven't pointed?

Comment: You do you need a separate copy?  You could just pass the model to the to the second frame.  Not sure why you're processing the `ResultSet` twice for

Comment: I have a JTable2 in frame1 and JTable1 in frame2. I want to copy send selected data from table2 to table1. how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

If you want to "copy" the selected data, then you will need to know what rows are selected, see [`JTable#getSelectedRows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows()).

You're making life difficult for yourself using `DbUtils` as you've lost the ability to just transfer the objects from one model to another.

The basic idea would be to copy the values from the original table into a new `TableModel` and pass that to the second window, something like

```
TableModel original = table.getModel();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(table.getSelectedRowCount(), original.getColumnCount());
for (int col = 0; col < original.getColumnCount(); col++) {
    model.addColumn(original.getColumnName(col));
}

int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < selectedRows.length; targetRow++) {
    int row = selectedRows[targetRow];
    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    for (int col = 0; col < original.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        model.setValueAt(original.getValueAt(modelRow, col), targetRow, col);
    }
}
```

for example.  Now you just need to pass `model` to the second window and apply it to the `JTable` contained within

Comment: okay. And how do i pass the model to the second window then ?

Comment: That would depend, do you have a reference to the second window?  May you could pass it via the constructor or create a method which accepts an instance of `TableModel`, which is outlined in [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: what if my other jtable is in another frame ?
how to i pass data then ?

Comment: See the point about having "a reference to the second window?"  If you don't have a reference to something, then you can't pass information to it.

Comment: and how do i do that? sorry im new to this.

Comment: Well, since you've not provided enough to 100% sure, I consider using something like `JFrame NewJFrame2 = new NewJFrame2(model);`, but you'll need to modify your source code to allow `NewJFrame2` to accept a `TableModel`, see the aforementioned tutorial for more details

Comment: and this i should write where ?

Comment: After you've created the new `TableModel`